# Retrieve Named Cell's Refers to Cell, not resultant value

Tags: excel, named

I have a Named Cell called "StandardSQFT" that is dynamic in the fact that it changes on particular sheet's Activate. For example:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
ActiveWorkbook.Names("StandardSQFT").RefersTo = "='Fuel Tank'!$C$40"
End Sub
```

No, I have another sheet that I want to now what cell/sheet "StandardSQFT" refers to , not the value.
I'd like to enter in a cell:

`=StandardSQFT.RefersTo` and see the result of: `='Fuel Tank'!$C$40`

Is this possible? The above doesn't work, nor does StandardSQFT.LinkedCell.

I'm sure this is simple so please go ahead and laugh at what I am missing here ...

Comment: `range("StandardSQFT").value` ?

Comment: Thanks but that gives an error also.

Comment: To be clear I don't want to retrieve it VBA but in a Cell on a worksheet.

Comment: Just type `=StandardSQFT` in a cell but it will error if the range is not defined.

Comment: If I do just that I get the resultant value of cell $C$40 on sheet 'Fuel Tank' but I want the .Refers to value, not the value entered in that cell.

Comment: What exactly should appear? I thought you wanted the result of `='Fuel Tank'!$C$40`? Why don't you add it to your VBA?

Comment: I do want that as a result but it does give me the error #NAME. If I just enter =StandardSQFT I get the value in that cell. But anyway, thanks for your time. What I did was when I assign the .RefersTo  I also had it change a Cell on the worksheet I want to edit and the evaluate that cell. It works well enough but still curious why I can't get the .RefersTo cell that it is pointing to.

Comment: `RefersTo` is a VBA property. You could use it in your event code.